# How to write Think or Swim Compound Value in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Can someone please help how to write the below script in tradingview pine scriptenter code here

```
input price = close;
input length = 10;

def tmp1 = if price > price[1] then price - price[1] else 0;
def tmp2 = if price[1] > price then price[1] - price else 0;
def d2 = sum(tmp1, length);
def d4 = sum(tmp2, length);
def cond = d2 + d4 == 0;
def ad3 = if cond then 0 else (d2 - d4) / (d2 + d4) * 100;
def coeff = 2 / (length + 1) * AbsValue(ad3) / 100;
def asd = **compoundValue("visible data" = coeff * price + (if IsNaN(asd[1]) then 0 else asd[1]) * (1 - coeff), "historical data" = price);**
plot VMA = asd;
```

Comment: Please explain, What is the desired resuly

Comment: i just saw this think or swim script and like it the way it is plotting , I am basically a trading view user, so seeking out help to convert it to pine script